# php continue "foreach" after return

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am working on a **WordPress** plugin for a specific theme but have a general question,
I have an array and want to do something with each object and return the result.
everything is Ok but the "**foreach**" only works for the first object of array and I think its because of "**return"** but for some reasons I cannot use "**echo**" instead of return.
this is my code:

```
    $cast_list = array(
        "composite_cast",
        "graphic_designer_cast",
        "product_manager_cast",
        "render_cast",
        "the3d_cast",
        "story_board_cast"
    );

    foreach ($cast_list as $value)
    {
        $user_field = get_field($value);    
    }

    return $user_field;
}
```

I have read other similar topics but passing the variable to another function to do the "return" job for me also not works

Comment: It's unclear from the code you've posted what exactly you're trying to achieve, but know this: if you return, execution stops. So returning within a loop is not ideal (unless you specifically need that pattern.) More likely you need to build up your data aggregately and then return all of it after the loop is complete.

Comment: I'm 103.5324% `return $user_field;` will return the **last** iteration of the array - not the first (unless there is code we're not seeing that's contributing to the `return`) -- you should echo the `$user_field` **within** the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your doubt:** the "foreach" only works for the first object of array and I think its because of "return"

**No** this not for `return` it's because of variable overwriting inside the `foreach()` loop every time. Actually you're not returning only the **first** element, here you're returning the **last** element because you're overwriting `$user_field` variable every time within `foreach()` loop

Try instead to push result to it using `$user_field[]` and then you're good to go

```
$cast_list = array(
    "composite_cast",
    "graphic_designer_cast",
    "product_manager_cast",
    "render_cast",
    "the3d_cast",
    "story_board_cast"
);

foreach ($cast_list as $value)
{
    $user_field[] = get_field($value);    
}

return $user_field;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the functions work until the `return` keyword. You need to create a new array and append all the edited elements to it and then return it.

```
$user_fields = array();
foreach ($cast_list as $value)
{
    array_push($user_fields, get_field($value));
}
return $user_fields;
```

Or you even can work on each *field* right in the loop and return nothing.

Comment: Or just `$user_field[] = get_field($value); `